# Удалить из строки первую цифру

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++

Программа переписывает из строки все буквы, пропуская цифры. А как сделать так, чтобы пропускалась только первая последовательность цифр? То есть, если строка "qwe23r5ty", то выведется "qwerty", а нужно чтобы было "qwer5ty"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char buffer[1024]; //Твоя строка которую вводишь
    char Result[1024] = { 0 }; //Результат
    cout << "Input string : ";
    gets_s(buffer);
    char* ptr = Result; //Указатель на строку Result
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++) //Обойти всю строку по-символьно
    {
        if (!isdigit((unsigned char)buffer[i])) //Если символ не цифра
            *ptr++ = buffer[i]; //то пишим этот символ в Result и сдвигаем указатель на 1 байт
    }
    cout << endl << "Result : " << Result;

}
```

Comment: Добавьте флаг "первая группа цифр уже была".

Comment: @Akina можно по-подробнее?

Comment: Сперва "цифр ещё не было". Идём, проверяем, копируем буквы. Наткнулись на цифру. Запоминаем "цифра уже была". Идём, пропускаем цифры. Наткнулись на букву. Запоминаем "цифры уже обработаны", и копируем всё подряд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Во первых:**  если вы не передаете количество читаемых элеменов в  `gets_s`, то эта функция не будет знать куда вставить завершающий символ `'\0'`, и буффер может остаться без завершающего символа. Если вы уж используете `std::cout` для вывода, то почему не использовать и `std::cin`  для более безопасного и наглядного ввода?

```
char buffer[1024]; //Твоя строка которую вводишь
char Result[1024] = { 0 }; //Результат
cout << "Input string : ";    
cin >> buffer;
```

Выполнить задуманное вами, можно разными способами, одним из которой является способ, предложенной  пользователем `Akina`. Можно также просто использовать существующие в стандарте функции копирования и конкетации, сначала копируя количество символов, пока не встретилась цифра, а потом конкетация остальной части:

```
int n = 0;
const char* ptr = buffer;
while (!isdigit(*ptr++)) ++n;
strncpy_s(Result, buffer, n);
while (isdigit(*ptr)) ++ptr;
strcat_s(Result, ptr);    
cout << endl << "Result : " << Result;
```

Можно и ничего не копировать, а читать только необходимое:

```
char buffer[1024]; //Твоя строка которую вводишь   
cout << "Input string : ";
int i = 0;
/*пока следующий не прочитанный символ
не является цифрой*/
while (!( isdigit(cin.peek()) )) {
    cin >> buffer[i++];
}
/*пока следующий не прочитанный символ\
является цифрой, пропускаем*/
while (isdigit(cin.peek())) 
    cin.ignore();    
//теперь читаем все остальные символы
while (cin >> buffer[i++]);
buffer[i] = 0;
cout << buffer;
```

P.S.
Теперь вернемся к началу наблюдений. Если вы используете инструменты из С++, такие как `std::cout` из заголовочного С++ файла  и т.п., то уж используйте `С++` строки вместо С_строк,  и лишнюю память не займете, и код будет компактней и читабельней.

Comment: В его варианте `gets_s` вполне работает без явного указания размера массива, так как он указан в объявлении (см. [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/gets-s-getws-s?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @AR-Hovsepyan у нас просто только одна лекция по данной теме была и сразу дали лабораторку, по этому тему я не очень шарю. Но нам посоветовали не вводить строки через cin(препод не сказал почему, мб личные убеждения)

В общем, спасибо за иформацию)

Comment: Ваня Марченко, я не знаю почему вам посоветовали(может просто задание такое выдали, иначе с таким успехом можно посоветовать не пользоваться cout), но это точно не та программа, где cin менее эфективен, зато он всегда удобнее и безопаснее.  Но главное тут не в этом, вы можете ввод осуществить и без потока ввода cin. Тут важно знать, что ту же задачу в С++ можно решать многими  способами, и   ответы здесь принадлежат не только вам, а и  многим, кому заинтересует данный вопрос. Я рад, если мой ответ и вам хоть чем то помог, хотябы в качестве информации. Желаю удачи!